# What to do when reviewing if a question is a duplicate but has been flagged as duplicate of a another question which is not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Let's say I am reviewing close votes and I see a Question A which is flagged as a duplicate of Question B.

However, Question A is not a duplicate of Question B, but a duplicate of Question C.

What should I do?

- Vote "Leave Open" to disagree with the flag, and then vote to close the question outside review.
- Vote "Close" in review.
- Doesn't matter.
- Something else.

Does it change if I have dupehammer superpowers?

Comment: Isn't it possible to VTC with the correct question? Just add the link on the close-dialog, you don't have to pick one of the existing ones.

Answer (score 7):

Most importantly, if it deserves to be closed then by no means should you be clicking the Leave Open button. Then the question is just one person closer to actually being left open.

Secondly, when reviewing a question in the Close Votes queue, you are **reviewing whether the question should be closed**. You are not agreeing or disagreeing with previous close reasons which have been selected. That's not the purpose of the queue and the validity of other close reasons is not something that should alter your decision there.

So, if the question should be closed - close it. If not, leave it open. If you feel another duplicate that ends up in the banner is not relevant, feel free to leave a comment stating so. "Hey, ignore this one and go to this one first."

Answer (score 5):

Vote to close as a duplicate of question C. Simple as that.

You don't have to pick one of the existing options.

Comment: Yes, I know I don't have to pick one of the existing options. But the question is if I should vote to close outside review after disagreeing with the flag, or if I should vote to close directly in review.

Comment: Close directly from review, why not?